# Variable value is still null even after assigning a value inside the listener block

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

My Textview had the current location value shown but when I do a log at the onCreateView, my currentLocation is null. Any advice on how to store the currentLocation inside the addOnSuccessListener task?

class EventNearMeFragment : Fragment() {

```
private lateinit var binding: FragmentEventNearMeBinding
private var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient? = null
private var currentLocation: Location? = null
private val vm: EventNearMeViewModel by activityViewModels()

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    binding = FragmentEventNearMeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireContext())
    fetchLocation()
    Log.d("current location value", currentLocation!!.latitude.toString() + currentLocation!!.longitude.toString())

    return binding.root
}

private fun fetchLocation() {
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(),android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        val requestCode = 1000
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(requireContext() as Activity, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), requestCode)
        when(requestCode){
            1000 -> fetchLocation()
            else -> return
        }
        return
    }
    val task = fusedLocationProviderClient?.lastLocation
        task?.addOnSuccessListener {
            location -> if(location != null) {
            this.currentLocation = location
            val geoCoder = Geocoder(requireContext(), Locale.getDefault())
            val addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(currentLocation!!.latitude, currentLocation!!.longitude, 1)
            Toast.makeText(context, addresses[0].getAddressLine(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            binding.lblAddress.text = addresses[0].getAddressLine(0)       
        }
        }

}
```

}

Comment: Your `fetchLocation()` function starts a task to get a location with a listener which will be called sometime in the future. So if you Log immediately after calling `fetchLocation()`, there hasn't been a chance for the listener to be called yet. I'll link your question to another one that has more detail about this case.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks for providing me the other question where the answers are very useful for me to understand about asynchronous operations. But yet I still did not managed to return value for my currentLocation. In my onCreateView, I changed it to fetchLocation { result -> currentLocation = result} and I did the callback.invoke(location) inside the listener as well as changing the function to become a callback function. Am I doing it right here? Sorry if this was an easy question but I am still learning about how these API operations works. xd

Comment: You can use the `currentLocation` **inside** your callback. Your callback will be fired some time in the future, so code outside your callback happens before the code inside your callback.

Comment: I do follow your way and it works. And i had to continue doing my function inside the callback which is not a good option haha. Thanks for your help again! Will try to figure how to enhance my code now. Thanks!